# ¿Cómo crear un sistema de ecuaciones lineales de forma iterativa con python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

estoy tratando de solucionar una ecuación diferencial ordinaria de segundo orden con valores en la frontera a través del método de diferencias finitas que sirve para discretizar la ecuación diferencial y poner la ecuación en términos de un sistema de ecuaciones lineales, sin embargo no sé como hacer que se me cree el sistema de ecuaciones de forma iterativa, agradecería si alguien puede ayudarme, dejo parte del código que he venido trabajando.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# se define un diccionario con la función externa y coeficientes de la ecuación diferencial; Los coeficientes A(x),B(X) Y C(X) además de la función externa f(x) tienen las claves 1,2,3 y 4 respectiviamente, hay que tener eso encuenta a la hora de quedar acceder a alguna de las funciones de coeficientes.
# dentro de la funciones lambda se puede modificar las funciones al gusto de quien edite el codigo
coefi={1:lambda x: np.sin(x),2:lambda x: np.cos(x),3:lambda x: x,4:lambda x:2*x}
cf=[(0,6),(5,10)] # se define una lista que contiene los valores en la frontera en forma de coordenada no mutable (x,y), el primer par de coordenadas (x,y) hace referencia al extremo izquierdo de la frontera y el segunda par de coordenadas hace referencia al extremo derecho de la frontera, si es necesario cambiarlos solametne modificar los valores numéricos dentro de los paréntesis
h=0.1 #tamaño de paso del proceso, modificar si se necesita
def FiniteDiferencies():
    n = int(cf[1][0] / h)
    xi = cf[0][0]
    #inicia la construcción de la matriz de coeficientes y el vector de terminos independientes
    mc=[]
    ti = []
    ti2 = []
    c1,c2,c3=0,0,0
    for e in range(n-2):
        xi=xi+h
        for ter in range(n-2):
            axi = (1 / h ** 2) * coefi[1](xi) - (1 / (2 * h)) * coefi[2](xi) #se calcula el coeficiente a
            bxi = (-2 / h ** 2) * coefi[1](xi) + coefi[3](xi) #se calcula el coeficiente b
            cxi = (1 / h ** 2) * coefi[1](xi) + (1 / (2 * h)) * coefi[2](xi) #Se calcula el coficiente c
            inxi = coefi[4](xi) #se calcula el termino indendiente
            if e==0: #verifica si está en la frontera izquierda
                f0x=cf[0][1]*-1*axi #si lo está entonces el valor de y0 paselo a la izquierda y sumelo al termino independiente
                inxi = inxi+f0x
            elif e==n-3: #verifica si está en la frontera derecha
                f0n=cf[1][1]*-1 #si lo están entonces el valor de yn paselo a la izquierda y sumelo al termino independiente
                inxi = coefi[4](xi)+f0n
            mc.append([axi,bxi, cxi,0]) #ingrese los coeficientes de la ecuación a la fila i
            ti2.append(inxi) #ingrese el valor del termino independiente al vector
```

Answer (score 1):

He llegado a la solución, resulta que al hacer un análisis sobre las diferencias centradas me di cuenta que la conformación de la matriz de coeficientes del sistema de ecuaciones lineales es un sistema tridiagonal, en donde el coeficientes de las ecuaciones con diferencias centradas llenan las tres diagonales, a causa de ese análisis implementé un código que pudiera calcular y almacenar el valor de esas tres diagonales en listas diferentes, posteriormente a través de la librería de numpy se hizo uso del método diag para construir una matriz según la diagonal a la cual pertenece, posterior esa matriz la resuelvo con el método linalg.solve. Adjunto el código a continuación.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# Se define una lista llamada coefi en la cual cada elemento se le define una posición de la siguiente forma [0,1,2,3,...,n] y el elemento en la posición 0,1,2,3,n es un diccionario
# Nota: Un diccionario es una estructura de datos parecida a una lista con la diferencia en que los elementos no se acceden por una posición si no por una clave, es decir que un elemento está definida por una clave y el elemento
# para acceder a los elementos del diccionario se tiene que especificar la clave de la siguiente forma: diccionario[clave]
# si se quiere agregar un elemento al diccionario entonces se tiene que hacer de la siguiente forma: diccionario{elementos_anteriores,clave:dato_a_agregar}
# dentro de cada elemento de la lista coefi existe un diccionario con la función externa y los coeficientes de la ecuación diferencial; Los coeficientes A(x),B(X),C(X) Y la función externa f(x) tienen las claves 1,2,3 y 4 respectivamente, hay que tener eso encuenta a la hora de querer acceder a los coeficientes de la EDO elegida.
# Finalmente para acceder a los coeficientes de un edo en particular tenemos que hacerlo de la siguiente manera coefi[posición_de_mi_ecuacion_en_la_lista][clave_de_mi_coeficiente_dentro_del_diccionario](parámetro_a_evaluar_en_el_coeficiente_de_la_edo)
# dentro de la funciones lambda se puede modificar las funciones al gusto de quien edite el codigo
# Nota 2: Si se va a ingresar una nueva ecuación diferencial entonces debe de ingresarse un nuevo elemento a la lista coefi
# El elemento que se vaya a agregar debe de ser un diccionario que obligatoriamente debe contener 4 datos
# Esos cuatro datos corresponde a los coeficiente A(X),B(X),C(X) y la función externa f(x)
# Cada dato del diccionario debe de contener una clave de 1 a 4, en donde la clave 1 corresponde al coeficiente A(x), la 2 al coeficiente B(x)
# Así sucesivamente hasta llegar a la clave 4 que corresponde a la función externa f(x)
coefi=[{1:lambda x: 1,2:lambda x: 0,3:lambda x: -0.01,4:lambda x: -0.2},{1:lambda x: 7,2:lambda x: -2,3:lambda x: -1,4:lambda x:-x},{1:lambda x: x**2,2:lambda x: -x,3:lambda x: -1,4:lambda x:2*x}]
# cfr es una lista que contiene en cada posición un diccionario en donde hay dos elementos con una clave, el primer elemento siempre corresponderá a la frontera izquierda y el segundo elemento corresponderá a la frontera derecha
# Nota si se quiere ingresar unas nuevas condiciones de frontera para una ecuación diferencial en específico, se debe ingresar una nueva posición en la lista
# el dato de esa posición debe de tener la misma estructura que la de la primera posición de la lista
# recordar que en una lista los datos se separan por comas
cfr=[{1:(0,40),2:(10,200)},{1:(0,5),2:(20,8)},{1:(1.962,0),2:(9.265,0)}]
funcanali=[lambda x:73.4523*np.exp(0.1*x)-53.4523*np.exp(-0.1*x)+20,lambda x:(-1.783e-4)*np.exp(((1+2*np.sqrt(2))/7)*x)+7.0001783*np.exp(((1-2*np.sqrt(2))/7)*x)+x-2,lambda x:0.03862212*np.float_power(x,(1+np.sqrt(2)))+2.33412631*np.float_power(x,(1-np.sqrt(2)))-x]
# cantidad de puntos, modificar si se necesita
n=10
def Graphs(id,ls,h):
    x=np.arange(cfr[id][1][0],cfr[id][2][0]+h,h) # se llena un vector con todos los valores de x
    y=funcanali[id](x) # se calculan los valores de la función en los x calculados
    plt.plot(x,y,label="Solución analítica")
    plt.plot(x,ls,'r--',label="Solución numérica")
    plt.xlabel("x")
    plt.ylabel("y")
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid()
    plt.title("Solución numérica vs analítica")
    plt.show()
def finitediferencies(id):
    ai, di, bi, ci, yi = [], [], [], [], [] # se definen las listas que van a contener los coeficientes de las ecuaciones lineales
    xi = cfr[id][1][0] #se trae la coordenada x de la frontera izquierda
    h=(cfr[id][2][0]-cfr[id][1][0])/n # se calculan el número de puntos a econctrar la solución
    for i in range(0,n-1): # empieza el bucle iterador para la variable i
        xi=xi+h # se incrementa el valor de xi para evaluar en el punto xi
        for j in range(0,n-1): # empieza el bucle iterador para la variable j
            if i==j: # si en la diagonal principal
                c2 = (-2 / h ** 2) * coefi[id][1](xi) + coefi[id][3](xi) # entonces calcule el coeficiente 2
                di.append(c2) # y haga una lista con los elementos de la diganonal principal
            if i==j-1: # si se está en la diagonal que está por encima de la principal
                c3 = (1 / h ** 2) * coefi[id][1](xi) + (1 / (2 * h)) * coefi[id][2](xi) #calcula el coeficiente 3
                ci.append(c3) #y haga una lista de valores  de la diagonal que está por encima de la diagonal principal
            if i==j+1: #si se está en la diagonal que está por debajo de la principal
                c1 = (1 / h ** 2) * coefi[id][1](xi) - (1 / (2 * h)) * coefi[id][2](xi) #calcule el cofiente 1
                ai.append(c1) # y haga una lista de valores con los elementos de la diagonal que está por debajo de la diagonal pricipal
        ti=coefi[id][4](xi) #calculo de los bi
        if i==0: # se verifica si se está en la ecuación 1
            ti=ti-((1 / h ** 2) * coefi[id][1](xi) - (1 / (2 * h)) * coefi[id][2](xi))*cfr[id][1][1] #si está en la ecuación 1 entonces se despeja el termino para suma cn bi
        elif i==n-2: # se verifica si se está la última ecuación
            ti=ti-((1 / h ** 2) * coefi[id][1](xi) + (1 / (2 * h)) * coefi[id][2](xi))*cfr[id][2][1] # si están en la última ecuación despeja el termino para sumar con bi
        bi.append(ti) #Se ingresa bi a la lista
    matriz = np.diag(di) + np.diag(ci, 1) + np.diag(ai, -1) # se construye la matriz tridiagonal
    sol=np.linalg.solve(matriz,bi) # se soluciona la matriz tridiagonal
    print("Resultados con la aproximación centrada, para un error de h^2 y un tamaño de paso de h="+str(h))
    xi=cfr[id][1][0]
    print("x="+str(xi)+"  y="+str(cfr[id][2][1])) # se muestra el resultado inicial
    ynum=[cfr[id][1][1]]
    for r in sol: # se recorre el vector solución
        xi=xi+h # se calcula el x para el cual se obtiene una solución de y
        print("x="+str(xi)+"  y="+str(r))
        ynum.append(r) # se guardan los valores del vector solución en otra lista para poder gráficar
    print("x=" + str(cfr[id][2][0]) + "  y=" + str(cfr[id][2][1])) #se muestra el resultado final
    ynum.append(cfr[id][2][1])
    Graphs(id,ynum,h) # se llama a una función que grafica las dos soluciones, si no se tiene función analítica para la función escogida, comentar esta línea con #

try:
    print("Actualmente hay "+str(len(coefi))+" ecuaciones diferenciales ingresadas")
    print("Las funciones están en una lista que van desde las posición 0 hasta "+str(len(coefi)-1)+", el id será esa posición en la lista")
    id=int(input("Ingrese el id de la ecuación diferencial para la cual se solucionará sobre un intervalo"))
    finitediferencies(id)
except:
    print("""Ha ocurrido un error al ejecutar el código, revisa si la información que ingresaste es válida""")
```

Comment: TBH no he entendido qué hace tu script, pero como sugerencia te recomiendo que separes la lógica del "printeo". Quiero decir, que cada función haga una cosa y la haga bien. Por ejemplo: 'finitediferencies' debería devolver 'id' 'ynum' y 'h' y escribir otra funcion que le pase esas variables a 'Graph'. De esta forma evitas bugs y te da flexibilidad, por ejemplo para decidir cómo y cuando mostrar la gráfica o pasar esos valores a otra función diferente.

Comment: Listo bro, muchísimas gracias por tu observación, mi script básicamente lo que hace es utilizar el método de diferencias finitas para encontrar la solución sobre un intervalo que previamente se ingresa en el código, para ello hago uso de una matriz de coeficientes en donde cálculo todas las entradas de la diagonal principal, la que está por encima de la principal y la que está por debajo de la principal en los dos ciclos for, posterior la soluciono con las librerías del método numpy y después grafico la solución analítica vs la numérica

Comment: Jajaja, me refiero a que no entiendo esas matemáticas pero gracias por la aclaración :)